# how to make fluid height via bootstrap or @media-query?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, fluid-layout

i use bootstrap for fluid grid system.

i have a div with class .`span6` and i set `heigth:200px` for this.

now i want when window is re-sizing the div's height decrease like as width.

http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/X8zu8/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="span6"></div>

        <div class="span3"></div>

        <div class="span3"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends what will be in the divs and how the site is designed...

If you just want to decrease the size than you have to make it via JS, or start positioning your elements absolute.

If the site is designed to be 100% height of the window, you can make the elements absolute and it will be easy.

But if the site isn't 100% of the window height, than the only solution is via javscript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why to use JS. On window re-sizing, i would probably prefer media querys for the div's.